# React Dropzone styles is not taking when we drop files to dropzone area

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

am working on react with Dropzone. 
my requirement is i do need to show Dropzone area a text like in the center when we drag files to drop area( text: you are inserting files) + a blue border in the drop area

my code looks like

```
          <Dropzone
            disableClick={true}
            className={styles.dropStyle}
            dropzoneActive={{ borderColor: 'green' }}
            onDrop={e => this.props.change(e)}
          >
            <div>...this is the dropzone area...</div>
           </DropZone>
```

Here  border color green is not coming , its taking only dropStyle css+ plus i need to show a text inside the div  **only** when we drag files to zone area.

I mean its a normal div with lot of assets, when **we drop** only css should apply( means dropzoneActive css should be visible )

Any fiddle will be highly appreciated